# css two div beside eachother without overlap on windows resize

Tags: css

The following is my html and css code

```
<body>
<div style="display: inline; postion: relative; float: left; width: 20%; min-height: 350px; background-color:red">
TESSSSSSSSSTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT123
</div>
<div style="display: inline; postion: relative; float: left; width:80%; min-height: 350px; background-color:green">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

On windows resize, two div overlaps, is there any way to avoid this? I want two divs to always stay in one line no matter what window size (also both divs contents gets wrapped inside each div).

appreciate any help, thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their `widths` are defined using the `%` value, thus they grow/shrink relative to the browser size. For your text to not overlap in the neighboring `<div>` add `word-break: break-all;` to your first `<div>` that contains the text .. also please mention which browser you are using.

[Example](http://jsbin.com/oximid/1)

Comment: Thanks, but beside text, I also have a div of content in the left div which gets covered by the right div.any solution?

Comment: Can you also give me a example when you have say a button on top right side of the left div?

Comment: I know I am giving you an example. when I have a text, its fine, but when another content such as a button or something else break does not work

Answer (score 0):

They don't overlap, their widths change according to `<body>`, they stay in the same line one next to the other.

Comment: If I put content in the left div and resize the window, the gradually go under the right div!

Comment: Ok then your question is wrong. What behavior do you want for the content?

Comment: no man, I got two div beside each other, and I got some content in each of them, when I resize the window, the right div comes over the left divs content. thats my problem. I know I can use break-all for left div. but it does not work when I have for example another div of content in the left div

Comment: You're not answering me: (if `break-all` doesn't works for you) what behavior do you expect?

Comment: say I have a button on the top right side of the left div, when I resize the window, the button gradually gets covered by the right div. I expect no over lap or my button not being covered

Answer (score 0):

The divs are not overlaping, your test text is simply without spaces, and the browser will only re-size text on spaces. Try adding spaces to the test text and you will see that the text will re-size (by now, you should also see that the divs actually do not overlap).

Also, if you set the elements to inline, there is really no point in having the elements floating left as you have done. If you are planning on useing the divs as a part of a website layout, I would suggest keeping them floating left which will keep the divs as block-elements, which is a allows more styling with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="firstDiv"></div>
<div class="secondDiv"></div>
```

css

```
.firstDiv {
    height:100px;
    width:60%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#222;
}
.secondDiv {
    height:100px;
    width:60%;
    float:left;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

use percentage `%` to make your div more fixeble 
[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/actef/)

Comment: these are on top of eachother

Comment: @ComeRun hi did you check the demo?

Comment: yeah man I want divs on one line. urs are on top of eachother